# Transaction fails with IJ000457, IJ000461 and IJ000356 on first time, but works thereafter

Tags: jpa, ejb, wildfly, jta

I am trying to run JSF application with JPA on Wildly server, I have the following code, there is an exception when trying to add employee at first time, but when trying another time, it works fine, I did not find the reason, please help.

session bean:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import model.Employee;

@Stateless
@Transactional(rollbackOn=Exception.class)
public class EmployeeBean {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="employee")
       private EntityManager em;

       public void create(Employee... gs) {
           if(em==null)
           {
               System.out.println("entitymanager is null");
               return;

           }


           try {
            for(Employee g : gs) {
                   em.persist(g);
               }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }

}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="employee" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/employee</jta-data-source>
        <class>model.Emp_Proj</class>
        <class>model.Emp_ProjPK</class>
        <class>model.Project</class>
        <class>model.Employee</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

standalone.xml

```
<datasources>
                <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/employee" pool-name="MysqlDS2" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysqld</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>123456</password>
                    </security>
                    <timeout>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>1000</idle-timeout-minutes>
                    </timeout>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="mysqld" module="com.mysql">
                        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
```

Error:

```
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1178) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:93) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    ... 77 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1882) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:115) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:50) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:358) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:91) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1166) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]
    ... 80 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:63) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:103) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:96) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.buildBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:152) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.getBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:141) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3102) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ... 86 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@68650790[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@3f714c71 connection handles=0 lastUse=1434318003661 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@2751af41 mcp=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@2337c020[pool=MysqlDS2] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@5a682437[connectionListener=68650790 connectionManager=63c8e891 warned=false currentXid=null productName=MySQL productVersion=5.6.16 jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/employee] txSync=null]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ... 103 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@68650790[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@3f714c71 connection handles=0 lastUse=1434318003661 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@2751af41 mcp=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@2337c020[pool=MysqlDS2] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@5a682437[connectionListener=68650790 connectionManager=63c8e891 warned=false currentXid=null productName=MySQL productVersion=5.6.16 jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/employee] txSync=null]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:773)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:516)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146)
    ... 106 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000461: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:546)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:768)
    ... 108 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: IJ000356: Failed to enlist: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings. tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a80105:-52c4393b:557df43a:9 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener$TransactionSynchronization.checkEnlisted(TxConnectionListener.java:812)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:362)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:539)
    ... 109 more
```

Comment: This is a tough one! A wild guess is your JDBC driver version isn't the appropriate one for your java version. What version of Java/MySQL driver/Wildfly?

Comment: I am using wildly 8.1.0, mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin mysql driver, and Java 1.7

Comment: For the aid of others, is Wildfly installed through HomeBrew, some other package manager, or manually?

Comment: It's manually installed.

Comment: which version of WildFly you are using?

Comment: I am using version 8.1

Comment: @jdev try to upgrade to 8.2 version

Comment: @SafwanHijazi, Thanks, It works now, maybe the version 8.1 has an issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's strange error, and happened with me, please try to disable jta in the datasource  like this **`jta="false"`**
Or upgrade WildFly to 8.2.0 Final version.

Comment: I'm using version 10.0.0.Final and still facing this issue, so changing to latest version won't help. It's probably a problem with configuration. I'll try your hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was having a very similar problem `java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected()`, then I tried to repeat the operation and it was sucessfull. Always the first operation was generating this error. Here i'm using wildfly-9.0.0.Final and after changing my standalone.xml with `datasource jta="false"` it worked.

Did some tests and it's good so far. Thank you.

Comment: This solution works fine on Wildfly14. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue and the cause was a missing `@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)` annotation at the bean class level. After I added it, the situation fixed.